# How can I display the articles according to the language that the user chooses?

Tags: laravel

I have a site that contains articles.

I made the main titles support multiple languages through localization,
but how can I store articles in the database in multiple languages?

and How can I display the articles according to the language that the user chooses?

Comment: Here is a simple articel on laravel  that does localisation...https://lokalise.com/blog/laravel-localization-step-by-step/

Comment: thank you but this article for the main titles on the site, but I need to make the articles in DB support that !

Comment: https://sebastiandedeyne.com/using-a-database-for-localization-in-laravel       Here is an example using database...

Comment: did it helped you...

Comment: Glad that i could help you...